# Rust: returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, iterator

I have this little piece of snippet of code. Why does the 2nd fail to compile?

```
fn apply (&self, text: Text) -> Text {
    // works fine
    let mut data = String::new();
    for c in text.data.chars() {
        let c = *self.mapping.get(&c).unwrap_or(&c);
        data.push(c);
    }
    return Text {
        data,
    };

    // not compile
    return Text {
        data: text.data.chars().map(|c| self.mapping.get(&c).unwrap_or(&c)).collect(),
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you include the compiler error in the question, and/or provide a stand-alone example that we can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comppiler tells you exacly why (which is why reading and posting compilation errors is useful:

```
8 |             data: text.data.chars().map(|c| self.mapping.get(&c).unwrap_or(&c)).collect()
  |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--^
  |                                             |                              |
  |                                             |                              `c` is borrowed here
  |                                             returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

In the case where the input `char` is not present in the mapping, it returns a reference to a local variable which is not allowed as... the reference would then be left [dangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), something rust does not allow.

The solution is the exact same as that used in the "works fine" version: dereference the callback's result, which will `Copy` the `&char` to a `char`, which is owned and can thus be returned with no lifetime concerns:

```rust
        Text {
            data: text.data.chars().map(|c| *self.mapping.get(&c).unwrap_or(&c)).collect()
        }
```

Alternatively you could `copied` the result of `HashMap::get` yielding an `Option<char>`, which would then be `unwrap_or`'d to `char`, fixing the issue for the same reasons:

```rust
        Text {
            data: text.data.chars().map(|c| self.mapping.get(&c).copied().unwrap_or(c)).collect()
        }
```