# Rust -- returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Tags: rust, solana

Read the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67086579/rust-returns-a-value-referencing-data-owned-by-the-current-function), but didn't find helpful.

I have the following struct & method implemented on it:

```rs
#[account]
pub struct Pool {
    pub version: u8,
    pub pool_bump: [u8; 1],

    /// Ownership & belonging
    pub tswap: Pubkey,
    pub creator: Pubkey,

    /// Collection stuff
    pub whitelist: Pubkey,

    /// Config
    pub config: PoolConfig,

    /// Accounting & tracking
    pub trade_count: u64,
    pub nfts_held: u32,
    pub is_active: bool,
}

impl Pool {
    pub fn pool_seeds(&self) -> [&[u8]; 7] {
        [
            self.tswap.as_ref(),
            self.creator.as_ref(),
            self.whitelist.as_ref(),
            &[self.config.pool_type as u8], //enum with repr(u8)
            &[self.config.curve_type as u8], //enum with repr(u8)
            &self.config.starting_price.to_le_bytes(), //u64
            &self.config.delta.to_le_bytes(), //u64
        ]
    }
}
```

Compiler isn't happy during compilation:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> programs/tensorswap/src/state.rs:90:9
   |
90 | /         [
91 | |             self.tswap.as_ref(),
92 | |             self.creator.as_ref(),
93 | |             self.whitelist.as_ref(),
...  |
97 | |             &self.config.delta.to_le_bytes(),
   | |              ------------------------------- temporary value created here
98 | |         ]
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Same error for all of last 4 varialbes.

I understand what the error is telling me, but I'm not sure how to solve it. Is there a good way?

Comment: sadly rust don't give a way to get a ref to a [u8] from a u64 (same for other numbers), but if you are okay with using unsafe code you could transmute a `&u64` to `&[u8; 8]`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0822dc6ec1d07b6e9b1ed1766e2d3cc). Only problem is that you can't choose if it's in little/big endian, it will be platform dependant.

Comment: Do you mean to return an array of `Vec<u8>`, perhaps?

Comment: what are you trying to archieve? are you trying to get the memory representation of your struct to create a seed ? in this case why not hash the struct to create the seed ? and please don't try to make a hash function yourself, I don't say you can't make a good one, its just that a lot of smart people have already done it. plz.

Comment: The problem here is not really Rust, it's really what you are trying to do, in the sense that even in other languages this wouldn't work (if you wrote this in C, it would compile, but it would still be an error — probably among the most common). This means that the only solution is to review your logic: either you really want to return a pointer, but therefore someone else has to own the value, or you can return [cow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)s, or you return owned values. It's hard to tell you which one is right (if any)because we don't know the rest of your program.